# Grails 1.3.4 Missing Dependency Issue

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-plugin

Where can I find the repo to download the missing dependencies listed below. I have tried following repositories but not able to find these depencecies.

```
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::

    :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    :: org.grails.plugins#hibernate;1.3.6!hibernate.zip

    :: org.grails.plugins#webflow;1.3.6!webflow.zip

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

My repositories are:

```
// repositories for dependency resolution
repositories {
    mavenRepo "https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins"
    mavenRepo "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core"
    mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/repo/"
    grailsPlugins()
    grailsHome()
    grailsCentral()

    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    mavenRepo "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org"
    mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
    mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
    mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Webflow:

Repo: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.grails/grails-webflow
Gradle: compile group: 'org.grails', name: 'grails-webflow', version: '1.3.6'

Hibernate:

Repo: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.grails/grails-gorm
Gradle: compile group: 'org.grails', name: 'grails-gorm', version: '1.3.6'